# links with non-ASCII characters don't work

Tags: bug

I'm trying to make a link to [http://www.google.com/search?q="на github"][1] for [Как правильно: «на GitHub» или «в GitHub»?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%C2%AB%D0%BD%D0%B0-github%C2%BB-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%C2%AB%D0%B2-github%C2%BB), but it doesn't seem to work, because of the Cyrillic characters in the link.

[1]: http://www.google.com/search?q="на github"

Comment: The unescaped space in the link is probably *part* of the problem there (parsing wise).

Comment: @animuson, yes, that, too; but even if the space is removed, there's still no link